# Using python in math

Tags: python, math, equation, polynomials, quadratic

Ok so i want to solve this equation through python but cant figure out what to do! I tried using for loops but that didn't work so well

Im new to python so can anyone suggest what I should do

```
RWBG-(WBR^2)-WBR-(BR^3)-(3BR^2)+2BR-(R^3)-(6R^2)+11R-6 = 0
```

R,W,B,G are different variables

```
for i in range(100):
    R == i
for i in range(100):
    W == i
for i in range(100):
    B == i
for i in range(100):
    G == i

if R*W*B*G-W*B*R**2-W*B*R-B*R**3-3*B*R**2+2*B*R-R**3-6*R**2+11*R-6 == 0:
    print(R)
    print(W)
    print(B)
    print(G)
```

Ive tried this but it isnt successful

Comment: Can you please format the expression a little better? I don't understand the variables you're giving.

Comment: Is each letter a variable?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you can post some specific code and explain what you want it to do that it doesn't do. In the absence of more information, I recommend you check out [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

Comment: Then multiply them... `R*W*B*G`

Comment: But do you want just to evaluate the expression?

Comment: Yeah thanks @Manoel Ribeiro

Comment: My answer probably solves it then

Comment: So should i set for loops to calculate what values of R,W,B,G work

Comment: Basically use brute force

Comment: What if your solution is non-integer? The your 'brute force' approach won't work at all. If you can guarantee that you have integer solutions, then your approach might work. Might. But you would need to use nested loops, with the `if` statement in the inner-most loop.

Comment: I believe this is a highly non-trivial problem if you want to solve this equation, and definitely not in the scope of this board.

Comment: Ok well im litterally brand new to python

Comment: That's not python your problem is with the maths. A programming language won't suddenly solve your problem, you need to know exactly what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each letter is a variable, and that you simply want to evaluate the expression, an easy Python script would be:

```
def equation (R,W,B,G,R):
    return R*W*B*G - W*B*(R**2) - W*B*R - B(R**3) - 3*B*(R**2) + 2*B*R - R**3 - 6*(R**2) + 11*R - 6
```

Comment: You've got too many arrrguments there, matey.  Compute Like A Pirate Day is next week.